# Symfony 2 - Post products within budget without persists

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

**Introduction:**

I am developing a system of budgets where the user can add during registration Products relating to this budget (the products are unique for every budget), these products are subject to change during the budget registration, for example, say I typed the price the wrong product and wish to change, I click on edit and it will allow me to edit the value of this product, so far so good.

**Issue:**

My problem is that as I still do not have the budget ID I do not relate to what the product means that the product does not belong to anything, this can be a problem if you register a budget and add some products and not finished saving the budget, the products will be at the base and no relationship.

**What i need:**

I need that when you add a product, this product does not persist completely, as if he was on a transaction, however I could edit it normally as if the bank already, but it would only really saved in the bank when I concluded the registration of my budget.

*Obs: I'm using Symfony 2 and Doctrine.*

Budget Registration screens. (Still images, still not functional)

**1 . Screen Register Budget**

**2 . Modal Product Registration**

**3 . List of products already registered in the budget**

[image: Screen Register Budget]

[image: Modal Product Registration]

[image: List of products already registered in the budget]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a budget persisted yet, how can you even print all the products related to it in the main page?

One way of doing this is to create a temporary budget while opening the "new budget page", that gets discarded if it's not saved within a specific time frame (maybe on a staging table/entity). This way, all the products will be associated to that temporary budget and when you persist the budget all persisted products will relate to the persisted object. With this logic, you may close the webpage and recover that information in a subsequent time (providing it has not expired).

Another way may be to NOT save the products while submitting the modal form but saving them somewhere temporary (a hidden field of the main page, session variables) so that nothing is saved on database until you press the "Save" button for the budget. This way, if the users closes the page without saving all data (budget AND products) would be lost.

Comment: Understand, i think this will solve my problem, thanks